# Efficiently storing polled objects in SQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have an application that "polls" objects in other resources and store their metadata in a postgreSQL DB.
In the end, I would like to query these days changes (object was not present between dates, object changes between dates, etc.)
Most of the objects are static, so instead of storing each poll result as a record (poll is very frequent), I though there might be a way to store/update a record only on object change/disappearance/reappearance.
Is there a known efficient way to model this kind of data?

UPDATE 1:

Example:
My application may, for example, pool a website every two minutes to see if it is online and stores the website's title.
I would like to save this information so I can later query my DB for

- sites that were online\offline between dates X and Y
- whether a site was online\offline between given dates
- has title of a website has changed between dates

Most websites will be online most of the time and with title unchanged. I thought there might be a way to store only state change such as

- online -> offline
- offline -> online
- online (title1) -> online (title2)

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more details to help us conceptualize what your use case / objects look like. A good starting place are examples of the objects / data (please update your post accordingly).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Edited my post with an example. Hopes it clarifies the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a row like (SiteId, Status, StatusDate) and check the last-known status with each poll.  If the status has changed, insert a new row with the new status and the current timestamp, otherwise update the StatusDate to show that the status is still current.

Or you could simply append new rows for each polling, and introduce a batch process that summarizes the polling details and deletes them after some time window.

Comment: Thanks, liked the batch process idea! I'll try both to see which one works better for me (In terms of implementation complexity).